# What's wrong with this function call?

Tags: php, http-headers

When I call `apache_request_headers()` in php to get the `X-Forwarded-For` header, it blanks out any and all page output. What am I doing wrong?

```
$header = apache_request_headers(); 
$ip = $header["X-Forwarded-For"];
```

If I comment out those two lines it works just fine, except for the obvious issue that now `$ip` isn't being set.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? Is PHP installed as an Apache module? Because it works only then.

Comment: Why not use `$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];`?

Comment: I presume you're using PHP as an Apache module? (Not CGI or running under IIS or something?)

Comment: be careful, X-Forwarded-For is a list of ip, seperated by commas, you need to take the last one.

Comment: While the alternative provided, BoltClock, does work, that wasn't the question. Pekka, why would it die silently without error? Shouldn't there be an error about the function not being declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual, its probably this:

```
"This function is only supported when PHP is installed as an Apache module."
```

Try

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

As mentioned in the comments above.